# How can I embed instruments into Propellerhead Reason 4?

Tags: reason

I use a lot of external Refills for production. They're usually stored in external drives and I sometimes forget which drive it's stored in.

I was wondering if there's a way I can "embed" a refill into an .rsn file so that I don't have to plug in my external drive that has the refill in order to be able to work with a file.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The only solution is Self-Contain song settings. However, it doesn't work with refills, it cannot be included into songs. So you would have to make a habit of saving your refills with your songs. . You can also watch this video: